# How to check atleast one checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have ascx page in that I have a grid in side that I have added radio button, I want to check at least one checkbox should be checked before unload the page or clicking on btn save.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="None" onrowcreated="grdTest_RowCreated">
  <asp:TemplateField >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" Rows="10" Columns="40" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"   Height="55px" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Save"/>            
        <span id="checkbox">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnTest"  runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Correct") %>' TextAlign="Left"  Height="28px" />
        </span>
      </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" Rows="10" Columns="40" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Save"/>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="rbtnTest" runat="server"  Enabled="true" TextAlign="Left"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

How is this possible plz some one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Validate_Checkbox()
{

    var chks=document.getElementsByTagName('input');   
    var hasChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
        {
            if (chks[i].checked)
                {
                    hasChecked = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
      if (hasChecked == false)
            {
                alert("Please select at least one checkbox..!");

                return false;
            }

            return true;
}     
</script>
```

and on Submit Button you have to write

```
OnClientClick="return Validate_Checkbox()"
```

Comment: how to check on page unload? when user click on some other tab

Comment: if I am already calling a Javascript suppose test1.js, so how to call this js, after showing this alert I want to call test1.js hows that possible

Comment: You can call the javascript on form unload like this.              <script type="text/javascript">  
 
        window.onunload = Validate_Checkbox();  
 
        function Validate_Checkbox()  
        {  
                alert('Done!');  
        }  
</script>